# jquery-ui Drag/Drop over event problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am having trouble when I use the droppables over event to change css for visual feedback. When the draggable is over the droppable item it works as expected. After the draggable has been dropped on the on the droppable item the mouse still shows an over state when it's rolled over an object that has had the draggable pass over it before the drop. Also the stop event isn't firing.

I can't use the hoverClass option because i want to the over state to appear differently based on the mouse position when the draggable is over the droppable.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

You can se an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/SurferJoe/26eU5/

Comment: This could be a bug, we are having troubles as well with this.